# How to get better log from big query schema error

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, jsonschema

I'm running in to the same problem as: [Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499053/error-while-reading-data-error-message-json-table-encountered-too-many-errors) and I'm pretty sure it has to do with the schema:

```
RuntimeError: BigQuery job beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP_... failed. Error Result: <ErrorProto location: 'gs://dataflow/tmp/bq_load/some_file'
     message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://some_file'
     reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs-ptransform-27']
```

The problem here is that I have a large schema (running dataflow jobs) and just checking it for small errors is tedious. Is there any way to see better error messages/get more logs that actually pinpoints which part of the schema is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have often the same issue with `Beam` `Python` and `BigQueryIO`, the error is not clear in this case and the bad fields in schema are not indicated.

To solve this kind of issue, I usually use a schema or object validation in the input element and use a dead letter queue for element in errors.

Then I sink the error to a `BigQuery` table for analysis.

I created a library to simplify error handling with `Beam` called [Asgarde](https://github.com/tosun-si/pasgarde) :

```py
# Beam pipeline with Asgarde library.
input_teams: PCollection[str] = p | 'Read' >> beam.Create(team_names)

result = (CollectionComposer.of(input_teams)
            .map('Map with country', lambda tname: TeamInfo(name=tname, country=team_countries[tname], city=''))
            .map('Map with city', lambda tinfo: TeamInfo(name=tinfo.name, country=tinfo.country, city=team_cities[tinfo.name]))
            .filter('Filter french team', lambda tinfo: tinfo.country == 'France'))

result_outputs: PCollection[TeamInfo] = result.outputs
result_failures: PCollection[Failure] = result.failures
```

A wrapper `CollectionComposer` is created from a `PCollection`, this structure returns :

- `PCollection` of good outputs
- `PCollection` of failures

The failure is represented by a `Failure` object :

```py
@dataclass
class Failure:
    pipeline_step: str
    input_element: str
    exception: Exception
```

You can sink the `Failure` `PCollection` to a `BigQuery` table for analysis.

You can also check this article [Dead letter queue for errors with Beam, Asgarde, Dataflow and alerting in real time](https://medium.com/google-cloud/dead-letter-queue-for-errors-with-beam-asgarde-dataflow-and-alerting-in-real-time-5745225e12b7)

I also share with you :

- [Native error handling example with Beam](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-python-dlq-native-beam-summit/blob/main/team_league/domain_ptransform/team_stats_transform.py)
- [Error handling example with Beam and Asgarde](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-python-dlq-asgarde-beam-summit/blob/main/team_league/domain_ptransform/team_stats_transform.py)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'll give it a try and see how it goes! :)